# How can I limit the number times of each user have permission to try login in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I work on an ASP.NET MVC project. I want to limit the number of times each user can try to login.

I will try to explain: when I go to the login page as a user and I want to login into my account, when I enter username and password and click on "submit" to verify data, if that data is correct, everything is OK; but if the data is not correct, the controller should record this attempt to login as a failed attempt.

I wish find a solution her and I'm so sorry about my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some kind of way to pass information about previous loggin trials to controller.

In my project I use database. I have table with IP, date, time, count of login trails as record.

If login failed I search for record(or add it if it's first failed attempt) and increment counter.

If login was successful then I search for this record and delete it.

In my project I assume limit of ten login trails, so if found record has count 10 then I show error with login block for x minutes.
Controller will check time and date of record of user which is attempting and if not x minutes passed then error.

If x minutes passed and again login not successful then count is set to 1.

It's quite simple